# How to access a separate Array inside of a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeBook
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting program\n\n");
        String[] STUDENT_NAMES = new String[] {"Adams", "Baker", "Campbell", "Dewey", "East"};
        int[][] STUDENT_GRADES = new int[5][3];
        
        loadGradeArray(STUDENT_GRADES);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < STUDENT_NAMES.length; i++) 
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s %5d %8d \n", STUDENT_NAMES[i], STUDENT_GRADES[i][0], STUDENT_GRADES[i][1]);
        }
            
        getStudentAverage(STUDENT_GRADES, STUDENT_NAMES);
        
    } //end main
    
    public static void getStudentAverage(int[][] grade, String[] name)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        
        for(int row = 0; row<grade.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<grade[row].length; col++)
            {
                sum = sum + grade[row][col];
            }
            
            average = sum/2;
            sum = 0;
            System.out.println("The average of Student " + (row+1) + Arrays.toString(name) + " is: " + average);

        }
        
    }
    
    
    public static void loadGradeArray(int[][] STUDENT_GRADES)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row<STUDENT_GRADES.length; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col<STUDENT_GRADES[row].length; col++)
            {
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][0] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[0][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][0] = 100;
                STUDENT_GRADES[1][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][0] = 84;
                STUDENT_GRADES[2][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][0] = 80;
                STUDENT_GRADES[3][1] = 75;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][0] = 50;
                STUDENT_GRADES[4][1] = 75;
            }
        }
    }
        
} //end class
```

Assignment for class has me creating a grade book for students using String[] to store first names, and int[5][3] to store two exam grades per student. Final product should give user the option the option of printing the class average for a test, or a students class grade

I am having trouble with the getStudentAverage method. I am confused on how to include the corresponding students name in the print statement. I want it to output something like this:

The average of Adam is: 75.0

The average of Baker  is: 87.5

The average of Campbell is: 79.5

The average of Dewey is: 77.5

The average of East is: 62.5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
System.out.println("The average of Student " + (row+1) + Arrays.toString(name) + " is: " + average);
```

to this

```
System.out.println("The average of " + name[row] + " is: " + average);
```

Comment: Knew it was something obvious like that. Don't know how I didn't think of that. Thanks